I have no idea how to troubleshoot this: "execution reverted (no data present; likely require(false)" Help?
I'm trying to run an arbitrage bot via local fork using ethers.js and hardhat. I keep getting this error when I run the contract:
error on trade instructions emitted V7: Error: execution reverted (no data present; likely require(false) occurred (action="estimateGas", data="0x", reason="require(false)", transaction={ "data": "0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb9226600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a11d8f0bb8e332", "from": "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266", "to": "0x54287AaB4D98eA51a3B1FBceE56dAf27E04a56A6" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.11.1)
    at makeError (/Users/MyPath/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:129:21)
    at getBuiltinCallException (/Users/MyPath/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/abi-coder.js:105:37)
    at AbiCoder.getBuiltinCallException (/Users/MyPath/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/abi-coder.js:206:16)
    at WebSocketProvider.getRpcError (/Users/MyPath/dfsBot/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:668:43)
    at /Users/MyPath/dfsBot/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:302:45
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'estimateGas',
  data: '0x',
  reason: 'require(false)',
  transaction: {
    to: '0x54287AaB4D98eA51a3B1FBceE56dAf27E04a56A6',
    data: '0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb9226600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a11d8f0bb8e332',
    from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266'
  },
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  shortMessage: 'execution reverted (no data present; likely require(false) occurred',
  info: {
    error: {
      code: -32603,
      message: 'Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string',
      data: [Object]
    },
    payload: {
      method: 'eth_estimateGas',
      params: [Array],
      id: 628,
      jsonrpc: '2.0'
    }
  }
}

I'm no expert at solidity, so I'm trying to debug this the best I can.  The most I can understand is that there seems to be a gas estimation issue, but I'm really not clear on how to fix it, and I don't really understand why it's feeding back no data as a result.
Here's a BUNCH of different files - I hope it's not too much of a data dump...
Here's the solidity contract:
contract ArbitrageFlashLoan {

    address public constant AAVE_LENDING_POOL_ADDRESS = 0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9; 
    address public uniswapV2Router;
    address public token0;
    address public token1;
    uint256 public fee;
    address private uniswapV2RouterAddress = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address private sushiswapRouterAddress = 0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506;

    struct TradeInstruction {
        address arbPair;
        bool startOnUniswap;
        address inputToken;
        address outputToken;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOut;
    }

    IAaveLendingPool public lendingPool;

    constructor() {

        fee = 90; 
        lendingPool = IAaveLendingPool(AAVE_LENDING_POOL_ADDRESS);
    
    }

    function executeSwaps(TradeInstruction[] calldata tradeInstructions) external {

        // Initialize dynamic array in storage
        TradeInstruction[] memory instructions = new TradeInstruction[](tradeInstructions.length);

        // Copy tradeInstructions into instructions
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tradeInstructions.length; i++) {
            instructions[i] = tradeInstructions[i];
        }

        // Loop through each trade instruction
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tradeInstructions.length; i++) {

        // Select router based on trade instruction
            address routerAddress = tradeInstructions[i].startOnUniswap ? uniswapV2RouterAddress : sushiswapRouterAddress;

            IUniswapV2Router02 router = IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress);

            address[] memory path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = tradeInstructions[i].inputToken;
            path[1] = tradeInstructions[i].outputToken;

            uint256 amountIn = i > 0 ? instructions[i - 1].amountOut : instructions[i].amountIn;

            //BREAKING HERE ---v

            uint256[] memory amounts = router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
                amountIn,
                instructions[i].amountOut,
                path,
                address(this),
                block.timestamp
            );

            instructions[i].amountOut = amounts[1];

            emit Test(amounts);
        }
    }
}

Here's how I call the contract in my javascript code:
const main = async () => {

    pairs = originalPairs.filter(p => p.arbPair != reservesExcluded.arbPair)

    pairs.map(async (pair, _) => {

        // Other code
        
        const swapEventFragment = pairContract.filters.Swap();
        pairContract.on(swapEventFragment, async() => {
                
                if (!isExecuting) {

                    isExecuting = true

                    const currentPair = pairArray.find((p) => p === pairContract);

                    const pathways = await dfs(currentPair, pair, reservesExcluded);
                        
                    if (!pathways || pathways.length === 0) {

                        console.log("\nNo Pathway Found")
                        console.log("-------------------------------\n")
                        isExecuting = false

                    } 

                    const profitability = await determineProfitability(pathways);

                    if (!profitability ) {

                        console.log("\nNo Profitable Path Found")
                        console.log("-------------------------------\n")

                    } else {

                        // Build The tradeInstructions Array

        }

    })   

}

// Other functions

const executeTrades = async (tradeInstructions, arbitrage, account) => {
    
    console.log(`Attempting Arbitrage...\n`)

    try {

        for (let i = 0; i < tradeInstructions.length; i++) {

            const amountIn = tradeInstructions[i].amountIn;

            const approvedTxn = await arbitrage.approve(account, amountIn);
            await approvedTxn.wait();

        }

        const tx = await arbitrage.executeSwaps(
            tradeInstructions,
            {
                gasLimit: '20000000', 
                value: amountIn
            }
        );

        await tx.wait();

        console.log("trade instructions emitted V7!\n");

    } catch (error) {

        console.error("error on trade instructions emitted V7:", error);

    }
}

Here's sample output for the tradeInstructions:
tradeInstructions
[
  {
    arbPair: '0x5201883feeb05822ce25c9af8ab41fc78ca73fa9',
    startOnUniswap: true,
    inputToken: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
    outputToken: '0x8290333ceF9e6D528dD5618Fb97a76f268f3EDD4',
    amountIn: '45349971464610610',
    amountOut: '2675243480905209519215'
  },
  {
    arbPair: '0x1241f4a348162d99379a23e73926cf0bfcbf131e',
    startOnUniswap: false,
    inputToken: '0x8290333ceF9e6D528dD5618Fb97a76f268f3EDD4',
    outputToken: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
    amountIn: '2.6752434809052096e+21',
    amountOut: '40997009082726606'
  }
]

Here's how I deploy the contract:
const { ethers, provider } = require("./helpers/initialization")
const fs = require('fs');
require("dotenv").config();
const config = require("./config.json")

// Declare the ABI and Bytecode file locations then create the combined ABI and Bytecode

// Set up Ethereum wallet

async function deploy() {

    const account = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.FAKE_PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
    
    const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(combinedABI, combinedBytecode, account);

    const overrides = {
        
        gasLimit: "6721975", // Adjust the gas limit as needed
        gasPrice: "200000000000", // Adjust the gas    price as needed

    };

    const contract = await factory.deploy(overrides);

    console.log(contract)

    console.log('Contract ABI:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(combinedABI));
    console.log('Contract deployed to:', contract.target);

}

deploy();

Any thoughts on how I could fix or at least get more data on this issue?

Something is failing, it could be that one of the tokens charges a fee and you have to call swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens (or some other variation).

Unless I'm reading the docs wrong, there's no return on that function.  Again, not strong in solidity, so may be misunderstanding this
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02
